# finding duplicate words in a string and print them using re

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need some help with printing duplicated last names in a text file (lower case and uppercase should be the same)
The program do not print words with numbers (i.e. if the number appeared in last name or in the first name the whole name is ignored)

for example:
my text file is :

```
Assaf Spanier, Assaf Din, Yo9ssi Levi, Yoram bibe9rman, David levi, Bibi Netanyahu, Amnon Levi, Ehud sPanier, Barak Spa7nier, Sara Neta4nyahu
```

the output should be:

```
Assaf

Assaf

David

Bibi

Amnon

Ehud

========

Spanier

Levi
```

```js
import re

def delete_numbers(line):
   words = re.sub(r'\w*\d\w*', '', line).strip()
   for t in re.split(r',', words):
      if len(t.split()) == 1:
         words = re.sub(t, '',words)
         words = re.sub(',,', '', words)
   return words


fname = input("Enter file name: ")
file = open(fname,"r")
for line in file.readlines():
   words = delete_numbers(line)
   first_name = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z]+)\s",words)
   for i in first_name:
      print(i)
   print("***")

a = ""
for t in re.split(r',', words):
  a+= (", ".join(t.split()[1:])) + " "
```

Comment: It looks to me like you are *way* over-using `re`. Most of your examples of `re.split` and `re.sub` could just use the normal string methods `.split` and `.replace`, try to save `re` for the heavy-lifting.

Comment: Does the order matter? Because you can simply map on the last names with basic `str.split()`.

Comment: As an aside, I suggest getting out of the habit of doing `for line in file.readlines()`. Instead, you can *iterate directly over the file-handler: `for line in file`, this is much more memory efficient, because you only have a single line in memory at a time, versus the whole file materialized into  list of lines. Not a big issue at this scale, but just a thought.

Comment: I need to use RE @zwer

Comment: Why do you **need** to use `re`? That makes no sense. Plain string methods would be faster and more reasonable here. I guess perhaps for checking if a line contains a digit. But for splitting on commas it is definitely over-kill.

Comment: @רוניתשחר - Why?

Comment: Side note, don't forget to close your file

Comment: to print the duplicated last names @zwer

Comment: But you **don't need `re` to accomplish that**.

Comment: I want to learn how to @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @רוניתשחר but this is a *terrible* example of where to use `re`. Half of programming is knowing the right tool to use. The other half is not re-inventing tools that already exist :)

Comment: Also, what *exactly* does your file look like? Is it all on a single line?

Comment: yes @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first let's start with an aside - opening files in an idiomatic way. Use the `with` statement, which *guarantees* your file will be closed. For small scripts, this isn't a big deal, but if you ever start writing longer-lived programs, memory leaks due to incorrectly closed files can come back to haunt you. Since your file has everything on a single line:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    data = f.read()
```

The file is now closed. This also encourages you to deal with your file immediately, and not leave it opened consuming resources unecessarily. Another aside, let's suppose you *did* have multiple lines. Instead of using `for line in f.readlines()`, use the following construct:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        do_stuff(line)
```

Since you don't actually need to keep the whole file, and only need to inspect each line, don't use `readlines()`. Only use `readlines()` if you want to keep a list of lines around, something like `lines = f.readlines()`.

OK, finally, data will look something like this:

```
>>> print(data)
Assaf Spanier, Assaf Din, Yo9ssi Levi, Yoram bibe9rman, David levi, Bibi Netanyahu, Amnon Levi, Ehud sPanier, Barak Spa7nier, Sara Neta4nyahu
```

Ok, so if you want to use regex here, I suggest the following approach:

```
>>> names_regex = re.compile(r"^(\D+)\s(\D+)$")
```

The patter here, `^(\D+)\s(\D+)$` uses the *non-digit* group, `\D` (the opposite of `\d`, the digit group), and the white-space group, `\s`. Also, it uses *anchors*, `^` and `$`, to anchor the pattern to the beginning and end of the text respectively. Also, the parentheses create capturing groups, which we will leverage. Try copy-pasting this into http://regexr.com/ and play around with it if you still don't understand. One important note, use raw-strings, i.e. `r"this is a raw string"` versus normal strings, `"this is a normal string"` (notice the `r`). This is because Python strings use some of the same escape characters as regex-patterns. This will help maintain your sanity. Ok, finally, I suggest using the grouping idiom, with a `dict`

```
>>> grouper = {}
```

Now, our loop:

```
>>> for fullname in data.split(','):
...     match = names_regex.search(fullname.strip())
...     if match:
...         first, last = match.group(1), match.group(2)
...         grouper.setdefault(last.title(), []).append(first.title())
...
```

Note, I used the `.title` method to normalize all our names to "Titlecase". `dict.setdefault` takes a key as it's first argument, and if the key doesn't exist, it *sets* the second argument as the value, and returns it. So, I am checking if the last-name, in title-case, exists in the `grouper` dict, and if not, setting it to an empty list, `[]`, then `append`ing to whatever is there!

Now pretty-printing for clarity:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(grouper)
{'Din': ['Assaf'],
 'Levi': ['David', 'Amnon'],
 'Netanyahu': ['Bibi'],
 'Spanier': ['Assaf', 'Ehud']}
```

This is a very useful data-structure. We can, for example, get all last-names with more than a single first name:

```
>>> for last, firsts in grouper.items():
...     if len(firsts) > 1:
...         print(last)
...
Spanier
Levi
```

So, putting it all together:

```
>>> grouper = {}
>>> names_regex = re.compile(r"^(\D+)\s(\D+)$")
>>> for fullname in data.split(','):
...     match = names_regex.search(fullname.strip())
...     if match:
...         first, last = match.group(1), match.group(2)
...         first, last = first.title(), last.title()
...         print(first)
...         grouper.setdefault(last, []).append(first)
...
Assaf
Assaf
David
Bibi
Amnon
Ehud
>>> for last, firsts in grouper.items():
...     if len(firsts) > 1:
...         print(last)
...
Spanier
Levi
```

Note, I have assumed order doesn't matter, so I used a normal `dict`. My output happens to be in the correct order because on Python 3.6, `dict`s are ordered! But don't rely on this, since it is an implementation detail and not a guarantee. Use `collections.OrderedDict` if you want to guarantee order.

Answer (score 0):

Fine, since you insist on doing it using regex you should strive to do it in a single call so you don't suffer the penalty of context switches. The best approach would be to write a pattern to capture all first/last names that don't include numbers, separated by a comma, let the regex engine capture them all and then iterate over the matches and, finally, map them to a dictionary so you can split them as a last name => first name map:

```
import collections
import re

text = "Assaf Spanier, Assaf Din, Yo9ssi Levi, Yoram bibe9rman, David levi, " \
       "Bibi Netanyahu, Amnon Levi, Ehud sPanier, Barak Spa7nier, Sara Neta4nyahu"

full_name = re.compile(r"(?:^|\s|,)([^\d\s]+)\s+([^\d\s]+)(?=>$|,)")  # compile the pattern

matches = collections.OrderedDict()  # store for the last=>first name map preserving order
for match in full_name.finditer(text):
    first_name = match.group(1)
    print(first_name)  # print the first name to match your desired output
    last_name = match.group(2).title()  # capitalize the last name for case-insensitivity
    if last_name in matches:  # repeated last name
        matches[last_name].append(first_name)  # add the first name to the map
    else:  # encountering this last name for the first time
        matches[last_name] = [first_name]  # initialize the map for this last name
print("========")  # print the separator...
# finally, print all the repeated last names to match your format
for k, v in matches.items():
    if len(v) > 1:  # print only those with more than one first name attached
        print(k)
```

And this will give you:

```
Assaf
Assaf
David
Bibi
Amnon
Ehud
========
Spanier
Levi
```

In addition, you have the full last name => first names match in `matches`.

When it comes to the pattern, let's break it down piece by piece:

```
(?:^|\s|,) - match the beginning of the string, whitespace or a comma (non-capturing)
  ([^\d\,]+) - followed by any number of characters that are not not digits or whitespace
               (capturing)
    \s+  - followed by one or more whitespace characters (non-capturing)
      ([^\d\s]+) - followed by the same pattern as for the first name (capturing)
         (?=>$|,) - followed by a comma or end of the string  (look-ahead, non-capturing)
```

The two captured groups (first and last name) are then referenced in the `match` object when we iterate over matches. Easy-peasy.